# Too Many touch points reported

Tags: android, javafx, gluon-mobile

I have implemented a Datepicker Dialog in Java fx using datepicker.showAntWait().ifPresent().
It works fine on Desktop. But on android devices, after open the datepicker, i have the error
"Too many touch points reporter "
I have jdk8u40. I use Gluon Mobil and JavaFx

Comment: This is a [bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8095826) to be fixed in Java 9.

Comment: Thanks. I will try the Java 9 and let you know if it works

Comment: If you can't update to java 9 you can can try to use reflaction on the touchPoint array in the Scene class,  reset it once the exception is thrown and also the other fields that is related in the Scene class, it worked for me. You will also need a try catch block on the entire app though to catch the Runtime exception